# Default select kendo combobox

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I use KendoUI ComboBox and I want to put a default select item.

In KendoUI ComboBox I didn't find the way to put the default value in text and not with index.

```
<script>
    $("#combobox").kendoComboBox({
        dataSource: [
            { id: 1, name: "Apples" },
            { id: 2, name: "Oranges" }
        ],
        dataTextField: "name",
        dataValueField: "id"
    });

    var combobox = $("#combobox").data("kendoComboBox");

    combobox.select(combobox.ul.children().eq(0));
</script>
```

Here is the example. How can convert it to put text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @SatyaRanjanSahoo says you should use `value` **but** you should use the `id` value otherwise you will be forcing a value that might not be in the DataSource.

Example, If you do:

```
var combobox = $("#combobox").data("kendoComboBox");
// Set Value
combobox.value("Apricot");
// Get Value
alert("Value is " + combobox.value());
```

this will show `Apricot` but this is not in the `DataSource` meanwhile, if you do:

```
var combobox = $("#combobox").data("kendoComboBox");
// Set Value
combobox.value(2);
// Get Value
alert("Value is " + combobox.value());
```

This will show `Oranges` that is the correct value for the item which `id` is `2`.

So, unless you are sure that the value set in `value` call is a valid `dataTextField` I would recommend using the `dataValueField`.

Check this in the following code snippet...

```js
$("#combobox").kendoComboBox({
  dataSource: [
    { id: 1, name: "Apples" },
    { id: 2, name: "Oranges" }
  ],
  dataTextField: "name",
  dataValueField: "id"
});

var combobox = $("#combobox").data("kendoComboBox");


// Set a valid value
combobox.value("Oranges");
alert("Value for Oranges is: " + combobox.value());

// Set an invalid value
combobox.value("Apricots");
alert("Value for Apricots is: " + combobox.value());
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<input id="combobox"/>
```

Comment: Well explained @OnaBai.

Answer (score 1):

To put text directly into combo-box:

```
 var combobox = $("#combobox").data("kendoComboBox");
 combobox.value("Oranges");
```

But, using the same approach anonymous text can be set into the combo-box which is not a part of the data-source.  i.e.

```
  combobox.value("XYZ");
```

So, its good to use index to set value to combo-box.